# Netsuite - Saved Search with Days Calculation Formula

Tags: sql, sql-server, netsuite

![enter image description here][1]I am trying to create a Saved Search in Netsuite that calculates the number of days between two dates in a summarized search.  I am attaching a screenshot of the Results tab for reference.  I have tried using a Numeric Formula field, as well as a Date/Time Formula field.  I have also tried every Summary Type available.  Is there another way to do this?  I just get an entire blank column when I run this.

As some background, I am trying to calculate how many days between when the system note was changed to Pending Accounting to when the system note was changed to Processed.

Thanks!

Update: It won't let me upload photos.  Here is the formula I am using:

```
(CASE WHEN {systemnotes.newvalue}
= 'Processed'THEN {systemnotes.date} END)-(CASE WHEN {systemnotes.newvalue}
='Pending Accounting'THEN {systemnotes.date} END)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are going to be able to evaluate this.

systemnotes.value can only have one value at each cell, which means that you can't have it be equal to Processed and Pending Accounting at the same time.

What you do in this case is something along the lines of

```
CASE WHEN {systemnotes.newvalue}= 'Processed' 
THEN TO_DATE({systemnotes.date}) 
ELSEIF {systemnotes.newvalue}='Pending Accounting' 
THEN TO_DATE({systemnotes.date})*-1 
ELSE 0 
END
```

And then do a sum on the whole thing. I'm pretty sure this won't work as this is not tested, but the idea is to declare on each cell the positive, negative or null value, and then add make NS add the whole column to summarise.

Also you might find issues for duplicate values so if the state goes back to a previous state you might get weird results.

Edit- see if you can find something to work with unix time, that might make life easier.

See reference for oracle sql: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm